# use Featureunion in scikit-learn to combine two pandas columns for tfidf

Tags: pandas, scikit-learn, sklearn-pandas

While using [this](http://zacstewart.com/2015/04/28/document-classification-with-scikit-learn.html) as a model for spam classification, I'd like to add an additional feature of the Subject plus the body.

I have all of my features in a pandas dataframe. For example, the subject is df['Subject'], the body is df['body_text'] and the spam/ham label is df['ham/spam']

I receive the following error:
TypeError: 'FeatureUnion' object is not iterable

How can I use both df['Subject'] and df['body_text'] as features all while running them through the pipeline function?

```
from sklearn.pipeline import FeatureUnion
features = df[['Subject', 'body_text']].values
combined_2 = FeatureUnion(list(features))

pipeline = Pipeline([
('count_vectorizer',  CountVectorizer(ngram_range=(1, 2))),
('tfidf_transformer',  TfidfTransformer()),
('classifier',  MultinomialNB())])

pipeline.fit(combined_2, df['ham/spam'])

k_fold = KFold(n=len(df), n_folds=6)
scores = []
confusion = numpy.array([[0, 0], [0, 0]])
for train_indices, test_indices in k_fold:
    train_text = combined_2.iloc[train_indices]
    train_y = df.iloc[test_indices]['ham/spam'].values

    test_text = combined_2.iloc[test_indices]
    test_y = df.iloc[test_indices]['ham/spam'].values

    pipeline.fit(train_text, train_y)
    predictions = pipeline.predict(test_text)
    prediction_prob = pipeline.predict_proba(test_text)

    confusion += confusion_matrix(test_y, predictions)
    score = f1_score(test_y, predictions, pos_label='spam')
    scores.append(score)
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

`FeatureUnion` was not meant to be used that way. It instead takes two feature extractors / vectorizers and applies them to the input. It does not take data in the constructor the way it is shown.

`CountVectorizer` is expecting a sequence of strings. The easiest way to provide it with that is to concatenate the strings together. That would pass both the text in both columns to the same `CountVectorizer`.

```
combined_2 = df['Subject'] + ' '  + df['body_text']
```

An alternative method would be to run `CountVectorizer` and optionally `TfidfTransformer` individually on each column, and then stack the results.

```
import scipy.sparse as sp

subject_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(...)
subject_vectors = subject_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['Subject'])

body_vectorizer = CountVectorizer(...)
body_vectors = body_vectorizer.fit_transform(df['body_text'])

combined_2 = sp.hstack([subject_vectors, body_vectors], format='csr')
```

A third option is to implement your own transformer that would extract a dataframe column.

```
class DataFrameColumnExtracter(TransformerMixin):

    def __init__(self, column):
        self.column = column

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def transform(self, X, y=None):
        return X[self.column]
```

In that case you could use `FeatureUnion` on two pipelines, each containing your custom transformer, then `CountVectorizer`.

```
subj_pipe = make_pipeline(
       DataFrameColumnExtracter('Subject'), 
       CountVectorizer()
)

body_pipe = make_pipeline(
       DataFrameColumnExtracter('body_text'), 
       CountVectorizer()
)

feature_union = make_union(subj_pipe, body_pipe)
```

This feature union of pipelines will take the dataframe and each pipeline will process its column. It will produce the concatenation of term count matrices from the two columns given.

```
 sparse_matrix_of_counts = feature_union.fit_transform(df)
```

This feature union can also be added as the first step in a larger pipeline.

Comment: I feel this is a good reference for the same as well. [FeatureUnion](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/hetero_feature_union.html#example-hetero-feature-union-py)

Comment: Exactly what I've been looking for. I wonder if this should have been part of sklearn out of the box.

Comment: @David I have tried your third option but it returns a "ValueError: Expected 2D array, got 1D array instead"