# Bag of words and length of notes for Classification (different types of features) using FeatureUnion()

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, scikit-learn, feature-extraction, text-classification

I am trying to do a binary classification task, mainly to classify notes in two classes. I have already implemented a bag of words- classification appraoch. I begin with a pandas DataFrame with the a 'text' column, which lists all the notes and a 'label' column with either 0 or 1. After splitting the data into train/test, the X_train data is a pandas series object with only the text in the rows. I constructed the pipeline below to classify the data based on a bag-of-words approach. (ofcourse with the imports needed to run the code)

```
pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('vect', CountVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocess, tokenizer=tokenizeText)),
    ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer()),
    ('clf', LogisticRegression())
])

parameters = {
    'vect__ngram_range': [(1,1), (1,2), (1,3)],  # unigrams or   bigrams # PAS AAN
    'clf__C': [0.001, 1, 10]
}

if __name__ == "__main__":
    # find the best parameters for both the feature extraction and the
    # classifier
    grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1, cv=5)

    print("Performing grid search...")
    print("pipeline:", [name for name, _ in pipeline.steps])
    print("parameters:")
    pprint(parameters)
    t0 = time()
    grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train) #PAS AAN
    print("done in %0.3fs" % (time() - t0))
    print()

    print("Best score: %0.3f" % grid_search.best_score_)
    print("Best parameters set:")
    best_parameters = grid_search.best_estimator_.get_params()
    for param_name in sorted(parameters.keys()):
        print("\t%s: %r" % (param_name, best_parameters[param_name]))
```

Now i want to also add the lenght of the notes (the text) as a feature. I looked into this post: [How to add another feature (length of text) to current bag of words classification? Scikit-learn](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39121104/how-to-add-another-feature-length-of-text-to-current-bag-of-words-classificati) and followed the suggested links, but am nog quite able to configure the right code with the use of the FeatureUnion() method of scikitlearn. The code i have which results in a error is below (i think it has something to do with the data format of X_train that i submit?)

First i constructed a 'Transformer':

```
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin

class LengthExtractor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    """Takes in dataframe, extracts road name column, outputs average word length"""

    def __init__(self):
        pass

    def average_word_length(self, name):
        """Helper code to compute average word length of a name"""
        lenght_list = []
        for i in range(len(name)):
            lenght_list.append(len(name[i].split()))
        return lenght_list

    def transform(self, df, y=None):
        """The workhorse of this feature extractor"""
        return df.apply(self.average_word_length)

    def fit(self, df, y=None):
        """Returns `self` unless something different happens in train and test"""
        return self
```

Then I tried to run the following pipline:

```
from sklearn.pipeline import Pipeline, FeatureUnion

pipeline = Pipeline([
    ('features', FeatureUnion([
       ('ngram_tf_idf', Pipeline([
          ('vect', CountVectorizer(preprocessor=preprocess,  tokenizer=tokenizeText)),
        ('tfidf', TfidfTransformer())
    ])),
   ('len', LengthExtractor()),
    ])),
  ('clf', LogisticRegression())
  ])

pipeline.fit(X_train, X_test)
y = pipeline.predict(y_train)
print(classification_report(y, y_test))
```

Probably i am doing something wrong when i create the new class as i am new to OOP. Some help would be really appreciated.

*** Edit: Data Example (note that i created this, the original data in in the dutch language)

X_train would look like:

```
11    patient has a visitor this morning everything went well
0     no problems occurd during the cisit of the patient
13    patient will exit his room this afternoon and will leave
12    patient is very agressive in his voice towards other patient 
24    today miss hit a nurse when she was passing by 
22    sir was in a conflict with another patient on the same ward
```

Name: Tekst, dtype: object

y_test would look like:

```
11    0
0     0
13    0
12    1
24    1
22    1
Name: Label, dtype: int64
```

The same data structure, format holds for the X_test and y_test. Please note that the 'tekst' data in X_train and X_test, is a string from which i already remove punctuation and lowercase.

The additional functions i created to preprocess (to get rid of numbers etc) and tokenization is the following:

```
def preprocess(text):
    newText = ''
    for c in text: 
        if ((c >= 'a' and c <= 'z') or (c >= 'A' and c <= 'Z') or c == ' '):
            newText = newText + c
        elif (c == '.' or c == '/' or ord(c) == 92):
            newText = newText + ' '
    return newText

from nltk import tokenize

def tokenizeText(text):
    "Tokenize the sentence"
    sentences = tokenize.sent_tokenize(text, language='dutch')
    word = tokenize.word_tokenize(text, language='dutch')
    return word
```

**EDIT-16-5-17: ERROR CODE:**

```
ValueError Traceback (most recent call   last)
<ipython-input-70-1e3e10829138> in <module>()
     12 ])
     13 
---> 14 pipeline.fit(X_train, X_test)
     15 y = pipeline.predict(y_train)
     16 print(classification_report(y, y_test))

/Users/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py   in fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    266             This estimator
    267         """
--> 268         Xt, fit_params = self._fit(X, y, **fit_params)
    269         if self._final_estimator is not None:
    270             self._final_estimator.fit(Xt, y, **fit_params)

/Users/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py  in _fit(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    232                 pass
    233             elif hasattr(transform, "fit_transform"):
--> 234                 Xt = transform.fit_transform(Xt, y,    **fit_params_steps[name])
    235             else:
    236                 Xt = transform.fit(Xt, y,   **fit_params_steps[name]) \

/Users/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/pipeline.py   in fit_transform(self, X, y, **fit_params)
    740         self._update_transformer_list(transformers)
    741         if any(sparse.issparse(f) for f in Xs):
--> 742             Xs = sparse.hstack(Xs).tocsr()
    743         else:
    744             Xs = np.hstack(Xs)

/Users/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in hstack(blocks, format, dtype)
    462 
    463     """
--> 464     return bmat([blocks], format=format, dtype=dtype)
    465 
    466 

/Users/jj/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/scipy/sparse/construct.py in bmat(blocks, format, dtype)
    579                 elif brow_lengths[i] != A.shape[0]:
    580                     raise ValueError('blocks[%d,:] has  incompatible '
--> 581                                      'row dimensions' % i)
    582 
    583                 if bcol_lengths[j] == 0:

ValueError: blocks[0,:] has incompatible row dimensions
```

Comment: Can you add a small reproducible sample data set and a desired data set?

Comment: I made  an edit on the question, sorry for the code blocks to show the example of the data format. Please note that X_train is a series object. Hope my question is clear now:)

Comment: yeah, it looks much better now! I'll try to reproduce it...

Comment: What is the error. Please post the full stack trace for that too