# Combine Sklearn TFIDF with Additional Data

Tags: pandas, numpy, sklearn-pandas

I am trying to prepare data for supervised learning. I have my Tfidf data, which was generated from a column in my dataframe called "merged"

```
vect = TfidfVectorizer(stop_words='english', use_idf=True, min_df=50, ngram_range=(1,2))
X = vect.fit_transform(merged['kws_name_desc'])
print X.shape
print type(X)

(57629, 11947)
<class 'scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix'>
```

But I also need to add additional columns to this matrix. For each document in the TFIDF matrix, I have a list of additional numeric features. Each list is length 40 and it's comprised of floats.

So for clarify, I have 57,629 lists of length 40 which I'd like to append on to my TDIDF result.

Currently, I have this in a DataFrame, example data: merged["other_data"]. Below is an example row from the merged["other_data"]

```
0.4329597715,0.3637511039,0.4893141843,0.35840...
```

How can I append the 57,629 rows of my dataframe column with the TF-IDF matrix? I honestly don't know where to begin and would appreciate any pointers/guidance.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [use Featureunion in scikit-learn to combine two pandas columns for tfidf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710281/use-featureunion-in-scikit-learn-to-combine-two-pandas-columns-for-tfidf)

Answer (score 3):

This will do the work.

```
`df1 = pd.DataFrame(X.toarray())   //Convert sparse matrix to array
 df2 = YOUR_DF of size 57k x 40

 newDf = pd.concat([df1, df2], axis = 1)`//newDf is the required dataframe
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out:

First: iterate over my pandas column and create a list of lists

```
for_np = []

for x in merged['other_data']:
    row = x.split(",")
    row2 = map(float, row)
    for_np.append(row2)
```

Then create a np array:

```
n = np.array(for_np)
```

Then use scipy.sparse.hstack on X (my original tfidf sparse matrix and my new matrix. I'll probably end-up reweighting these 40-d vectors if they do not improve the classification results, but this approach worked!

```
import scipy.sparse

X = scipy.sparse.hstack([X, n])
```

Comment: I am sure i looked around and overlook what I was missing trying to add a column. Somebody on another question made it clear but it just clicked on this one line above.

Comment: oups hit return, hstack(X_train_tfidf,X_shp) did not work but hstack([X_train_tfidf,X_shp]) did work and the difference is in the [ ].

Comment: That was really an interesting question and solution. Can you add some idea on if you scaled the extra columns or used them as it is?

Comment: @IU5er - if I recall correctly, I experimented with various weightings for the tfidf features, but they did not improve my results much, so I dropped them. I could have perhaps appended a PCA'd down version of the results but the outcome likely would have been the same. I think combining NLP style features with more generic features is still a pretty open ended issue/problem. In a more recent problem, I've created binary features, based on whether or not a training observation contains a word, or contains one of many words, thus avoiding tons of new features.

Answer (score 0):

You could have a look at the answer to this question:

[use Featureunion in scikit-learn to combine two pandas columns for tfidf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710281/use-featureunion-in-scikit-learn-to-combine-two-pandas-columns-for-tfidf)

Obviously, the anwers given should work, but as soon as you want your classifier to make predictions, you definitely want to work with pipelines and feature unions.